# Finding coarser topology and homeomorphism between R and two tangent circles

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau$ be the usual topology on the real line $\mathbb{R}$. Does there exists a topology $\tau_{0} \subset \tau$ such that $(\mathbb{R},\tau_{0})$ is homeomorphic to the 
figure eight? Also, is it possible to find a topology $\tau_{0} \subset \tau$ and a quotient space with this topology such that this space is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

What's the trick for this one?

Comment: @Theo Buehler: We can identify the two end points of 0 and 1 and to get a circle. But $\mathbb{S}^{1}$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. Can you please explain a little bit more your hint?

Comment: Decide that $0 \in \mathbb{R}$ should be mapped to the point with a crossing. How should you define the neighborhoods of $0$? Moreover, what do you know about quotient spaces of compact spaces?

Comment: In other words: choose $0$ as the crossing point and parameterize the figure eight by the reals in such a way that the ends of the real line approach $0$ again.

Comment: @Theo Buehler: Thanks, I will try this.

Answer (score 2):

We let $\tau_{0}$ be the subset of open sets of $\tau$ consisting of $U$ in $\tau$ so that if $U$ contains $0$ then $U$ contains both some interval $(a,\infty)$ and some interval $(-\infty,b)$.  This essentially glues $\infty$ and $-\infty$ to $0$ giving a figure eight.

$0$ is the intersection of the circles, $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ is one branch and $\mathbb{R}^{-}$ is the other.

Comment: +1: That's precisely what I tried to explain (without strictly giving it away) in my comments. You haven't answered the second question, yet :)

Comment: @Theo: Thinking!

Comment: I gave a hint in my comments (Moreover, ...)